# Unsatisfiable premises in propositional logic, how do they affect proofs?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm currently solving some of the assignments from my Mathematical Logic course and I'm solving some exercises of the form $T,A \vDash B$ and I'm wondering how having an Unsatisfiable statement A would affect my reasoning.

For example: Prove if the following is true or false.

$A,B \vDash C \iff  A \vDash (B \to C) $

$(\Rightarrow)$ This direction is trivial.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $\alpha$ be the truth function. if $\alpha(A)=1$ then $\alpha(B\to C)=1$ Then it follows that:

1. $\alpha(B)=0$
2. $\alpha(B)=\alpha(C)=1$

So B could be Unsatisfiable and $A \vDash (B \to C)$ would be true even in the event that $\alpha(C)=0$. However, how does the case of B being unsatisfiable affect my reasoning for the rest of the proof? Since it is in the premises of $A,B \vDash C$ do I treat B like it could be satisfied? Would this fall in case 2 and make me assume that $\alpha(C)=1$?

Simply put, should I care about a premise being unsatisfiable? I know that when it comes to deductions there's a distinction between valid and sound arguments, do I make a similar distinction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don’t need to care about when $B$ is not satisfied $A,B\models C$ means that for every interpretation $\phi$, if $\phi(A)=1$ and $\phi(B)=1$ then $\phi(C)=1$. For any interpretation if $B$ is false then the statement is vacously true.

Comment: Thank you, quick follow-up question on this particular problem: the double implication is still false right? If I take B and C to be both unsatisfiable does this provide a suitable counterexample to prove that $\Leftarrow$ is false (since no matter what $\phi(C)$ will be false while $\phi(B \to C)$ is a tautology?

Comment: No it is true. So what if B and C is false? Think back to the definition of the models symbol.